# Can tzedakah be given from cryptocurrency

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity, contemporary-halacha, yoreh-deah, cryptocurrency

What does the Halacha say about giving tzedakah from cryptocurrency? Does one fulfill the mitzvah of donating tzedakah as charity if they donate cryptocurrency like Bitcoin, or no? The reason I ask is because cryptocurrency isn’t exactly similar to traditional currency in value.

Comment: In what respect is it not similar? There's no rule that tzedakah has to be in government-issued fiat.

Comment: The SEC treats cryptocurrency similarly to stock holdings, and you can certainly give stocks as tsedska. The valuation may be more complicated when it comes to maaser, but it's permitted

Comment: It can only be given to crypto Jews in secret.

Comment: https://www.toraland.org.il/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%98/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94/%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%91%D7%A2-%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%98%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9D-%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91-%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%91%D7%A2-%D7%A2%D7%A4%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94/#_ftn17 - this should answer your question. I know its an Hebrew but it would take some time to translate though, so sorry for that